# Can you use Shiro for Grails without Roles and Permissions?

Tags: grails, shiro, role

I wonder if you can use Shiro-Plugin for Grails without having permissions and roles enabled?

In our current Project, we have an external database with just username and password and I am not able to create the permissions and roles table.
Is there a way to implement one Shiro user with automatic permission to all Domains without role-management?

Answer (score 2):

From Shioro plugin  [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-shiro/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html)

Create a class in src/groovy or src/java that implements the `grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.ShiroPermissionResolver` interface, and define the 
`Set<String> resolvePermissions(String username)` 
method any way you like. Register your bean as the shiroPermissionResolver bean in resources.groovy, for example

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.MyShiroPermissionResolver
beans = {
   shiroPermissionResolver(MyShiroPermissionResolver)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the information. Great start and sounds perfectly Fitting, but can you please provide more information for the implementation in my Project? I did it like the documentation said, but the database is still created and (more important) still used!
Do I have to hook it somewhere else? I really followed the steps in the documention and tried it again and again.